# How to specify VertexCoordinates as geographic coordinates of cities?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have been very busy these days with giving the `VertexCoordinates` of the cities the geographic coordinates from `CityData["CityName","Coordinates"]` of the cities. Could somebody please help me on writing algorithm?

```
Graph[{"Uppsala" -> "Marsta", "Marsta" -> "Uppsala", 
  "UpplandsVasby" -> "Sollentuna", "Sollentuna" -> "UpplandsVasby", 
  "UpplandsVasby" -> "Marsta", "Marsta" -> "UpplandsVasby", 
  "Stockholm" -> "Boo", "Boo" -> "Stockholm", 
  "Stockholm" -> "Lidingo", "Lidingo" -> "Stockholm", 
  "Stockholm" -> "Sollentuna", "Sollentuna" -> "Stockholm", 
  "Stockholm" -> "Taby", "Taby" -> "Stockholm"}, 
 VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

Comment: Which `Graph[]`? Can you maybe show what you've already done in *Mathematica*?

Comment: please see result

Comment: Are you saying that you would like to plot the graph laid out in such a way that the vertices are placed according to their geographic location?

Comment: Exactly!!My graph is just simple here but yes my problem is how to locate vertices on their geographical coordinates and second step to show it in the map.Not just a Plot but the graph itself!!!When I want to show the flow on the vertices.

Comment: Try ref/VertexCoordinates and ref/CityData in the help?

Comment: Hi,Yes of course I used them but not enough!I am talking about algorithm that locates ,for example 1000 cities on their geographic locations.This is not about limited 10 or 20 numbers.This is not as easy as help examples!

Comment: If it works for 10 why wouldn't it work for 1000?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could extract coordinates using CityData and set it by SetProperty.

```
g = Graph[{"Uppsala" -> "Marsta", "Marsta" -> "Uppsala", 
"UpplandsVasby" -> "Sollentuna", "Sollentuna" -> "UpplandsVasby", 
"UpplandsVasby" -> "Marsta", "Marsta" -> "UpplandsVasby", 
"Stockholm" -> "Boo", "Boo" -> "Stockholm", 
"Stockholm" -> "Lidingo", "Lidingo" -> "Stockholm", 
"Stockholm" -> "Sollentuna", "Sollentuna" -> "Stockholm", 
"Stockholm" -> "Taby", "Taby" -> "Stockholm"}, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 40];

coords = CityData[#, "Coordinates"] & /@ VertexList[g];

SetProperty[g, {VertexCoordinates -> Reverse[coords, 2], 
  Prolog -> {Gray, CountryData["Sweden", "Polygon"]}}]
```

[image]

If SetProperty doesn't work (v9.0.0)

```
cities = {"Uppsala", "Marsta", "UpplandsVasby", "Sollentuna", 
"Stockholm", "Boo", "Lidingo", "Taby"};

coords = CityData[#, "Coordinates"] & /@ cities;

g = Graph[
cities, {"Uppsala" -> "Marsta", "Marsta" -> "Uppsala", 
 "UpplandsVasby" -> "Sollentuna", "Sollentuna" -> "UpplandsVasby", 
 "UpplandsVasby" -> "Marsta", "Marsta" -> "UpplandsVasby", 
 "Stockholm" -> "Boo", "Boo" -> "Stockholm", 
 "Stockholm" -> "Lidingo", "Lidingo" -> "Stockholm", 
 "Stockholm" -> "Sollentuna", "Sollentuna" -> "Stockholm", 
 "Stockholm" -> "Taby", "Taby" -> "Stockholm"}, 
   VertexCoordinates -> Reverse[coords, 2], 
   Prolog -> {Gray, CountryData["Sweden", "Polygon"]}, 
   VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 40]
```

Comment: thats great !!But when i am evaluating your proposed codes, it just gives me the simple Graph that I had!!Without Sweden Map and coordinates!!What could be wrong?Do you have output in the Graph?

Comment: Which version of Mathematica are you using? In v 9.0.1 it works fine. If it doesn't work, you can just add option when you construct graph or reconstruct graph like: Graph[VertexList[g], EdgeList[g], VertexCoordinates->.., Prolog->...]

Comment: black means "it's defined", so nothing wrong with it. did you try to build graph with coords? I added that version..

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use `GraphPlot[]` instead if I need to depict the graph with other primitives, so here's my take:

```
cityGraph = {"Uppsala" -> "Marsta", "Marsta" -> "Uppsala", "UpplandsVasby" -> "Sollentuna",
             "Sollentuna" -> "UpplandsVasby", "UpplandsVasby" -> "Marsta",
             "Marsta" -> "UpplandsVasby", "Stockholm" -> "Boo", "Boo" -> "Stockholm",
             "Stockholm" -> "Lidingo", "Lidingo" -> "Stockholm",
             "Stockholm" -> "Sollentuna", "Sollentuna" -> "Stockholm",
             "Stockholm" -> "Taby", "Taby" -> "Stockholm"}

GraphPlot[cityGraph, Background -> ColorData["Legacy", "PowderBlue"], 
          EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Blue, Line[#]} &), MultiedgeStyle -> 1/20,
          PlotRange -> {{17, 19}, {58, 60}}, 
          Prolog -> {Gray, CountryData["Sweden", {"FullPolygon", "Equirectangular"}]}, 
          VertexCoordinateRules ->
          Map[# -> Reverse[CityData[{#, "Sweden"}, "Coordinates"]] &,
              VertexList[Graph[cityGraph]]], VertexLabeling -> Tooltip, 
          VertexRenderingFunction -> ({Directive[AbsolutePointSize[4], Red],
                                       Tooltip[Point[#1], #2]} &)]
```

[image: Swedish city graph]

(If executed in *Mathematica*, there should be tooltips associated with each vertex.)

Comment: I suppose it ought to be explicitly noted that the coordinates in the polygon returned by `CountryData[]` are in `(long, lat)` format, while `CityData[]` coordinates return in `(lat, long)` format.

Comment: Your coordinates comment about CountryData and CityData and their differences is really amazing !!!Many Thanks!!!Thats very helpful to know that!!But about your suggestion to use GraphPlot the point is I want to show the optimized flow in the my Graph then better to use new version 9 availabilities.I wonder by using GraphPlot I can use "FlowGraph" capabilities?!

Comment: Can you maybe edit your question to show the fancy `Graph[]` with flows that you want to be embedded into a map?

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion .I will definitely do that But on that way I have to explain many other things not related to issue.After developing whole GraphNetwork I will upload it as sample later.

Comment: It doesn't have to be the entire network. You've already supplied a minimal example; now, how would you put the flows into this small graph you've presented?